# How to add multiple rows using a single insert statement. Using the way in the description

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SQL> insert into patient
2  values('&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp');
Enter value for pno: p3
Enter value for pname: mansell
Enter value for title: mr
Enter value for dob: 23-may-61
Enter value for children: 2
Enter value for gp: Dr.Williams
old   2: values('&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp')
new   2: values('p3','mansell','mr',23-may-61,2,'Dr.Williams')
values('p3','mansell','mr',23-may-61,2,'Dr.Williams')

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

This used to work.i really dont understand how to make it work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is almost certainly caused by the column `dob`. You're not inserting a date or a date literal, you're inserting a random string, that is being interpreted as a column name.

As a general rule *always explicitly convert dates into dates*.

You have [2 options](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1ac7/1) in SQL*Plus, you can insert an [ANSI date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

```
insert into patient (dob)
values ( date '&dob')
```

where `&dob` is in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

You can also explicitly convert the column into a date using the [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) function.

```
insert into patient (dob)
values ( to_date('&dob','yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

where `&dob` is of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`. This is known as a datetime format-model of which there's a [long list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) you can play around with.

All of this assumes that the column `dob` is a *date*. If it's not please change it to one. It's never worth the hassle of storing dates as a string. I would highly recommend always explicitly storing century as well. How is Oracle to know whether you're talking about 2067 or 1967?

Guffa's answer takes care of the multiple row element of your question.

Answer (score 0):

***ORA-00984 Error***

This error most commonly occurs when **You try to include a column name** in the **VALUES** clause of an INSERT statement.

Then

You can check the values that you inserted AND columns names of your tables and make sure that there are not the same.

Reference

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00984.php

Answer (score 0):

You end the query with the semi-colon, after that you can't continue to add to the query.

You can't add more `value` statements after the `insert`, but you can use `insert all`:

```
insert all
into patient values('&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp')
into patient values('&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp')
into patient values('&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp')
select * from dual;
```

(Possibly you would need different parameter names for each row.)

You can also insert from a `select`:

```
insert into patient
select '&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp' from dual
union all
select '&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp' from dual
union all
select '&pno','&pname','&title',&dob,&children,'&gp' from dual;
```

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Comment: In Oracle you need to select from something.